# Discontionous heatmap in R

Tags: r, heatmap, pheatmap

I wish to create something similar to the following types of discontinuous heat map in R:

[image]

[image]

My data is arranged as follows:

```
k_e percent time
 ..   ..     ..
 ..   ..     ..
```

I wish `k_e` to be x-axis, `percent` on y-axis and `time` to denote the color.

All links I could find plotted a continuous matrix  http://www.r-bloggers.com/ggheat-a-ggplot2-style-heatmap-function/ or interpolated. But I wish neither of the aforementioned, I want to plot discontinuous heatmap as in the images above.

Comment: If you "*wish neither of the aforementioned*", what do you wish then? Moreover, it would be helpful if you give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?s=1|4.4776)

Comment: If more than one data points fall into the same bin, shall the weights ("time") get averaged?

Comment: @ziggystar Yes, forgot to mention that, how is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: @ziggystar okay sorry didnt check you code, you had already mentioned it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one is a hexbin plot
If your (x,y) pairs are unique, you can do an x y plot, if that's what you want, you can try using base R plot functions:

```
x <- runif(100)
y<-runif(100)
time<-runif(100)

pal <- colorRampPalette(c('white','black'))
#cut creates 10 breaks and classify all the values in the time vector in
#one of the breaks, each of these values is then indexed by a color in the
#pal colorRampPalette.

cols <- pal(10)[as.numeric(cut(time,breaks = 10))]

#plot(x,y) creates the plot, pch sets the symbol to use and col the color 
of the points
plot(x,y,pch=19,col = cols)
```

With ggplot, you can also try:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x,y,color=time)
```

Comment: can you add comments for the last two lines please?

Comment: can you please specify using qplot how can i set the label for color?

Answer (score 1):

## Generate data

```
d <- data.frame(x=runif(100),y=runif(100),w=runif(100))
```

## Using `ggplot2`

```
require(ggplot2)
```

### Sample Count

The following code produces a discontinuous heatmap where color represents the number of items falling into a bin:

```
ggplot(d,aes(x=x,y=y)) + stat_bin2d(bins=10)
```

[image]

### Average weight

The following code creates a discontinuous heatmap where color represents the average value of variable `w` for all samples inside the current bin.

```
ggplot(d,aes(x=x,y=y,z=w)) + stat_summary2d(bins=10)
```

[image]