# Setting the color label and varying the color palette in qplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

1. Using the code below, i can set the labels for x and y axis, but can't set the label for color that is `cyl` here. The [documentation](http://127.0.0.1:13246/library/ggplot2/html/qplot.html) provides no way around.

   ```
   qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars, colour=cyl,xlab="MPG",ylab="WT")
   ```

[image]

2. How can I vary the color palette herein `qplot`? So, I wish to do something like in the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28233935/discontionous-heatmap-in-r) below:

   ```
   x <- runif(100)
   y<-runif(100)
   time<-runif(100)  
   pal <- colorRampPalette(c('white','black'))
   cols <- pal(10)[as.numeric(cut(time,breaks = 10))]
   plot(x,y,pch=19,col = cols)
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `scale_colour_continuous` for both tasks.

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = cyl, xlab = "MPG", ylab = "WT") +
  scale_colour_continuous(name = "Cylinders", low = "white", high = "black")
```

Here, the `name` parameter is the label for the colour scale. The parameters `low` and `high` denote the lower and upper limits of the continuous colour scale.

[image]

---

If you want to specify a continuous colour scale with three colours, you can use `scale_colour_gradient2`:

```
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = cyl, xlab = "MPG", ylab = "WT") +
  scale_colour_gradient2(name = "Cylinders", midpoint = median(mtcars$cyl),
                         low = "red", mid = "green", high = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!How can specify more than 2 colors?