# Interpolate from discontinuous data to plot a heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242842/setting-the-color-label-and-varying-the-color-palette-in-qplot) below I can get a discontinuous heatmap.

```
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = cyl, xlab = "MPG", ylab = "WT") +
  scale_colour_gradient2(name = "Cylinders", midpoint = median(mtcars$cyl),
                         low = "red", mid = "green", high = "black")
```

[image]

I wish to intrapolate this data to plot a continuous heatmap. But at the same time using qplot for plotting if possible.

Comment: Based on what criterion is the interpolation to be done?

Comment: Interpolation of cyl from wt and mpg, I guess.

Comment: Hum, I may be dense, but could you better describe what the result would ook like? Also, how does a motor with 4.75 cylinders look like?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik this is just sample set, I am implementing on something else which make more sense in terms of relation, but cant upload the data.

Comment: Then find a dataset that exhibits the same degree of coverage. It is still unclear what you want done. At the moment you are coloring points on continuous measurements rather than regions in  a discontinuous  grid:  which is what heatmaps do.

Comment: @BondedDust Something of this sort ggplot(df,aes(x=k_e,y=percent,z=time)) + stat_summary2d(bins=9)

Comment: But it is essentially an average though.